# Finding the prime factorizations of the numbers in the range $[1,10^8]$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, sieve-theory

I want to find out prime factorization of all numbers between $[1,10^8]$ in $O(\sqrt{N})$.

I read a lot of material on divisors and prime factorization and finally found that if I have Sieve of Eratosthenes having primes upto $10^4$,I can find out prime factorization of numbers between $[1,10^8]$ ? But How do I do that ?

Comment: If you divide $N$ with every prime from $1$ to $\sqrt{N}$, the result is either $1$ or prime.

Comment: Why the effort to generate all the factorizations for such small numbers considering that even trial division takes far less than a second to factor any such number on a normal calculator on a computer ? Do you really need the table ? (I am just curious)

Comment: @Peter The concept is more important to me. If I can apply this on small numbers then I can apply it on big integers as well.